# Will Cobalt provide reference cdm (content decryption module) for widevine/playerady drm porting?

Tags: cobalt

As far as I know, cobalt will support widevine/playready drm playback, and we are trying to port on our platform with TEE support.

We have already done the starboard/player.h porting and I want to say the reference code for player did a great help! But when I try to start starboard/drm.h porting (at Cobalt 6.14197), I only find a little code related to drm. (e.g Starboard_decryptor, some stub implementation for drm.h API).

Do we need to implement our own content decryption module to handle license parsing, policy, etc., or will cobalt provide the reference cdm (which will be great) and we can use our OEMCrypto module to finish the rest part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cobalt is able to support any DRM system compatible with the Encrypted Media Extensions, but this has only been fully proven out with both PlayReady and Widevine on deployed products.

Licensing makes it difficult to provide an open-source reference integration with Widevine or PlayReady, so it is currently up to the platform implementer to integrate the code to generate license challenges, install keys, and decrypt samples before decoding. Note that you should not need to change any code in src/media to do this, you should be able to accomplish this by only implementing Starboard player/drm/media APIs.

You may be able to directly contact the business entities involved to get access to a non-open-source reference implementation.